# How do I use UNION with multi query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the number of employees in each department also as per their title for example
Finance department

```
Senior Staff = 12137
Staff = 5207
Manager = 2
```

I need to do the same for all departments in ONE query as I have to visualize it in Tableau.
Here is my SQL script.

```
set @dept_id='d002';
call new_procedure_total_emp_dept(@dept_id ,@result);

(select dn,staff_title, count(staff_title), (count(staff_title)/@result)*100  from 
 (
SELECT d.dept_name as dn, ti.title as staff_title FROM dept_emp de
    join titles ti using (emp_no)
    join departments d on d.dept_no = de.dept_no
    where de.dept_no = 'd002'  
    group by  de.emp_no
) as staff_no
 group by staff_title
 )
 
union

(
select dn,staff_title, count(staff_title), (count(staff_title)/17786)*100  from 
 (
SELECT d.dept_name as dn, ti.title as staff_title FROM dept_emp de
    join titles ti using (emp_no)
    join departments d on d.dept_no = de.dept_no
     where de.dept_no = 'd003'  
    group by  de.emp_no
) as staff_no
 group by staff_title
) 
 ;
```

Comment: What's differentiates the 2 staff in finance?

Comment: You forgot to add the question to your question?

Comment: You should re-read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html). there are too much '()' in this query, or they are at the wrong place.